# Specifying code analysis setting in TFS 2010 build

Tags: tfsbuild, code-analysis

In the build definition of TFS 2010, when "Perform Code Analysis" set to "Always" how can I specify a custom code analysis rules file?

The build flavour is "Release".

I prefer not to set "AsConfigured" for "Perform Code Analysis" so that the settings are picked from proj file.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to use the "MSBuild Arguments" entry in your build process parameters configuration to provide a `/property` command line entry that will be passed to MSBuild, thereby allowing override of the `CodeAnalysisRuleSet` property value to be applied.

Depending on how you have set up the CodeAnalysisRuleSet property values in your existing projects, you may also need to tweak the value assignments to be conditional on the pre-existing value being empty.  If you need to do this, you might want to consider taking the opportunity to move the code analysis configuration for all projects into a separate .targets file so that they can be tweaked more easily in the future.

Comment: nice solution, but cannot seem to figure it out. (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms164311.aspx). I might have go down the "AsConfigured" route...... if I cannot figure it out.. Will mark this as answer.

Answer (score 0):

<strike>I dont think you can specify a custom code analysis ruleset file if you switch to `Always`.</strike>

(based on [Nicole's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8726519/specifying-code-analysis-setting-in-tfs-2010-build/8728616#8728616))

I think if you set the action to `Always` the assigned ruleset file for the current build flavor is used.

Based on this you need to assign the custom ruleset file with VS to your projects like discribed [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/habibh/archive/2009/08/12/create-your-own-code-analysis-rule-set-using-visual-studio-team-system-2010.aspx) or via `menu->Analyze->Configure Code Analysis for Solution/Projects`.